# Python 3.5 string format: How to add a thousands-separator and also right justify?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

How would I get a string that is equal to:

```
'    100,000.23'
```

Given that I have the variable

```
num = 100000.23
```

I can right justify with:

```
num = 100000.23
'{:>10.2f}'.format(num)
```

and I can thousands separate with:

```
num = 100000.23
'{:,}'.format(num)
```

But how can I do both at the same time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Combine the two by adding a comma following the alignment instruction:

```
>>> '{:>12,.2f}'.format(num)
'  100,000.23'
```

***Explanation***
For reference: [Format Specification Mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
{:       >      12         ,               .2         f      }
        ^^^     ^^        ^^^              ^^^       ^^^
       align   width  grouping_option   precision   type
```

Comment: I swear I've tried this before posting. This works. Thank you.

Comment: For reference [PEP 378 -- Format Specifier for Thousands Separator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/) includes an example with width, comma, precision, and floating point (but not alignment).

Comment: And extra points for the layout field that breaks the formatting down.